# Why no IChangeProxyTarget on IInvocation instances generated by ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxyTypeWithTarget via InheritanceInvocationTypeGenerator?

Tags: .net, castle, castle-dynamicproxy

Is it by design to prevent changing the proxy target for concrete types? If so, why?

**Background:**

I have a concrete class that I want to proxy. Further, I want to replace the target of the proxy at some point in the workflow. I've attempted to use `IChangeProxyTarget` in order to change the proxy target, however, this doesn't seem possible given that the `InheritanceInvocationTypeGenerator` which is created for `IInvocation` instances generated on classes always passes `false` to the `canChangeTarget` parameter on the `InvocationTypeGenerator` base constructor.

I believe I can replace enough of the generator lookup machinery in the driving `IProxyBuilder` to get this value to be `true` (and, indeed, forcing the value to be `true` in the debugger generates an `IInvocation` type which implements `IChangeProxyTarget`), however, I'm wondering why this is not more easily accessible.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, it's not there because it hasn't been implemented. From the top of my head I don't see any reason not to do it.